# How to use meta_query to check if a meta field has something set?

Tags: meta-query

(Wordpress 4.3.1)

I'm running a custom loop and only want to include posts that have file uploaded to a custom field: audio_file.

I have tried many solutions around the web and so far nothing works.

Can I use meta_query to check if a key has a value?

Here is my current attempt:

```
 global $post;      

 $args = array(
    'post_type'      => array (
                        'podcast',
                        'event',
                        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',     
    'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'meta_query'     => array (
                            'key' => 'audio_file',
                            'value' => '' ,
                            'compare' => '!=',
                            //'type'    => 'date',
                             ),
    );

    global $wp_query;

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
```

The intended result here is to display posts where 'audio_file' is not empty.

Thanks.
(Wordpress 4.3.1)

Comment: Also, updating WP to latest version is always a good idea from the security point of view (especially if other people have tested it and proved that it's safe and doesn't break everybody's sites or plugins).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, meta_query must be an array **within** an array as it is intended for advanced queries using 'relation'.

```
meta_query => array (
    array (
        //'relation' => 'OR',
        'key' => 'audio_file', //The field to check.
        'value' => '', //The value of the field.
        'compare' => '!=', //Conditional statement used on the value.
    ),  
),
```

The conditional '!=' not-equal to '' (null) returns true if a file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone. This will look for meta value, if exists and is not empty.

```
'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'AND',
    [
        'key'     => 'your_key',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ],
    // Don't want empty values
    [
        'key'     => 'your_key',
        'value'   => '',
        'compare' => '!=',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use meta_query to check if a key has a value?

Any value? [Use `EXISTS`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
'meta_query'     => array (
                        'key' => 'audio_file',
                        'value' => '' ,
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                        'type'    => 'date',
                         ),
);
```

I don't know why your uploaded file would be a `date` type though. I'd expect it to `binary` or maybe `char`

Comment: Right... missed that from a previous attempt to detect the date field. Perhaps 'type' is unnecessary anyway... I tried EXISTS and no luck...

Comment: Yes, it may not be necessary at all

Answer (score 2):

It seems the ***type*** of value is essential now. I couldn't get the meta query working correctly without using the type. Significantly, while checking the value existence.

This code doesn't work now.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'meta_key',
        'value'   => '',
        'compare' => '!=',
    ),
),
```

This one works.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'meta_key',
        'value'   => '',
        'compare' => '!=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
),
```

The only difference is the ***type***.